# Get distinct records with a join left

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I know there are a lot of threads like that on SO but i still can't figure out what's wrong with my code. My models are:

#### User

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
end
```

#### Event

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :venue
end
```

#### Venue

```
class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
end
```

What i'm trying to do is to get all the recent venues used by a user (through the events he have created). My activerecord chaing is:

```
User
  .first
  .events
  .joins(:venue)
  .select('venues.id, venues.name, venues.address, events.beginning_at')
  .uniq('venues.id')
```

and it produces the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(venues.id), venues.name, venues.address, events.beginning_at 
FROM "events" INNER JOIN "venues" ON "venues"."id" = "events"."venue_id" 
WHERE "events"."user_id" = $1  
ORDER BY "events"."beginning_at" ASC  [["user_id", 1]]
```

However, what it gives me is a quite "randomish" list of recently used venues. ATM all the events are assigned to the same venue and the query above gives me ALL of those venues (so it goes down to one venue multiplied by number of all events that user created). What's more interesting - that query gives me 9 results but when i remove the DISTINCT method, i get 20 results (while there is just one venue in my db)

Can you give me any tip on what am i doing wrong?

Comment: How `Event` and `Venue` both contain `#belongs_to`, one should be `has_one` ,...right ?

Comment: yes, you're completely right, original question fixed

Comment: Your edit now makes sense.. I got stuck there earlier..

Comment: Can you tell me what you actually want to query, it will help to fix your one or propose a new one'

Comment: Well, as i've said under my `Venue` model code, i want to get all the `venues` `user` has recently used in his `events`

Comment: What happens if you run that sql directly against your database?

Comment: when i run that query in pure SQL (well, a bit modified version without that user_id variable passing thing) it returns me the exact same result (duplicated results). What's more interesting - that query gives me 9 results but when i remove the DISTINCT method, i get 20 results (while there is just one venue in my db)

Comment: Can your provide an sql fiddle?

Comment: Distinct doesn't work how you think it does. (In fact, according to the MySQL docs, your statement is not valid!) If, as those docs say, you think of DISTINCT being a shorthand for GROUP BY (all selected columns), that might well explain your results.